# Using diff3 on a mercurial merge via command line

Tags: linux, mercurial, diff3

I'm sitting at a screen split in 3 in Putty showing my files.  I can't figure out what I need to Google in order to find documentation on how to navigate the command line UI for KDIFF3.  I'm trying to figure out how to go line by line or conflict by conflict or take a whole file altogether.  Can you guys help me find a manual or tell me how I can navigate this GUI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean the "command line UI for kdiff3".  Kdiff3 is a GUI application with an easily found usermanual.  Are you sure you're not looking at vimdiff or something else?